# How to change Dynamics CRM 2016 Grid view default filter option 30 days to all record?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

In my grid view, it is showing the upcoming next 30 days record on the default load of the view. If I change 30 days to all then it show all expected data. How I can set default 30 days to all filter option into my grid view on load? So that I can get my expected data on grid view load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no supported approach to set the default dropdown filter on OOB home grid or associated activities view. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/162569/set-default-filter-to-all-on-activities)

But you can create a view/dashboard for activities without such filters and add that in sitemap for direct navigation. [Read more](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/dominicjarvis/2017/03/08/editing-the-site-map-in-dynamics-365-using-the-built-in-site-map-designer)